# ¿Cómo dibujar el tronco de un Árbol de Navidad en Java de asteriscos sin llegar a espaciar?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando poner el tronco de mi árbol de navidad con asteriscos. No consigo poner la base del tronco en el ultimo bucle donde tengo el `System.out.println("     ***")` sin llegar a espaciar los asteriscos. Ósea lo que busco es que me rellene con espacios hasta llegar a la mitad del árbol y entonces ahí me dibuje el tronco.

He aqui mi codigo:

```
public class ArbolNavidad {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
         
         System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
         
         int numero=sc.nextInt();
         
         numero=numero*2-1;
         
         
         for (int i=1;i<=numero; i+=2) {
             
             for (int j=1;j<=numero-i;j+=2) {
                 
                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
        for (int k=1;k<=i;k++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
         System.out.println();
         }
         
         for(int i=1;i<=2;i++) {
             
             System.out.println("            ***");
         }
        }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcula un offset que sería `numero` menos el tamaño del tronco del arbol que es 3, y el resultado dividido entre 2.

Luego imprimir los espacios del offset y después colocar el tronco.

```
int offset = (numero - 3) / 2;

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    
    for (int j = 0; j < offset; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println("***"); //
}
```

Comment: Buenas Tardes compañero, he tenido que modificar el segundo bucle la condicion     j <offset-1, debido a que como usted me lo habia enviado no estaba totalmente alineado. Muchas gracias por la respuesta la he entendido perfectamente.